# How to print long string in actions of break points in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I write this demo program just to explain my question. It doesn't do anything useful:

```
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::string strMsg = "This is a very very long message, long enough that Visual Studio can't output it entirely. If you don't believe, just try it yourself and you'll see. What? I'm not long enough? Now it will be enough. You'll see ellipses at the end.";
    return 0;
}
```

Then I add a break point at `return 0;`, with an action to print `strMsg` to *Output Window*.

[image]

The printed string looks like:

> strMsg = "This is a very very long message, long enough that Visual Studio can't output it entirely. If you don't believe, just try it yourself and you'll see. What? I'm not long enough? Now it will be enough. ...

Please notice the `...` at the end of the printed message. It's because the string is too long to be printed entirely.

Is there any way to solve this, so Visual Studio can print the whole string?

Comment: This might not be an option for you in your real case, but just out of interest: what happens if you insert newlines in the string?

Comment: @Jeremy You mean `\n`? The character will be print as it is, e.g. `"abc\n"` will be printed as `abc\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the full value of the string by putting a breakpoint on the line and then selecting the variable name. You should then see a small dropdown that allows you to view as text, xml etc. This allows you to use the text visualiser.

In real time code then you either need to print the value to a console using `printf` or `cout` or print to a file or log.

[image]

Comment: That's true. But sometimes I need the program to continue executing (without pausing) when hit break point. For example, for some time-sensitive occasion.

Comment: You should really use some logging framework then. Printing to a console is going to slow your application down especially in time critical code.

Comment: You are probably right. But log can't cover all cases/variables, I still need to use *Log a message to Output Window* sometimes.

Comment: @MartinZhai why cant't it? Actually that's exactly what logging is for

Comment: @bolov It needs too much effort to add full log in a huge project (millions of lines of code)..

Comment: @MartinZhai Millions of lines of code and not proper logging mechanism? Ouch wouldn't like to be involved with that